# CodeIgniter: Form values to model function

Tags: model-view-controller, forms, function, codeigniter, send

I'm pretty new to the MVC structure and I wan't to do things so close to right as possible. Thats why I ask this question.

I have a form in a view-file. After information has been put into the form and the user have pressed the submit button I wan't to access the information in a function in my model-file.

How do I do this the right way?

Usually, when not using CodeIgniter, i would have done something like this to pass the information to the function:

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $this->the_function($_POST['the_values']);
}
?>
```

But after read a couple of search hits, what I have come up with, is that this is the wrong way to do it using an MVC pattern. Is that correct?

How should I do it the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following flow should be followed when handling a form request, which is just like any basic request for any page.

- Form gets submitted to a controller
- Controller gets the information via `$this->input->get` or `$this->input->post` (these are automatially available by CI, no library/helper loading needed)
- Controller loads any needed models and acts on the models with this information such as:

  - `$this->Comment_Model->get_comments($this->input->get('post_id'));`
- Controller has the information it needs from the model and selects appropriate view

  - `$this->load->view('display_comment', $data_from_the_model);`

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Sweet "function" the "$this->input->post" :) Thanks a lot!